# issues with Makefile and linking to graphic libraries for all OS

Tags: gcc, makefile, mingw, x11

this is my first post here and please bear with me if something goes off ! 
So, I am trying to compile executables using gcc/make, to make them distributable to all OS ( Win/Mac/Linux). I have attached a relevant snippet of my Makefile here.I understand I need to statically link the graphic libraries (maybe others libraries too , I am not sure) to "taxi_D"(seen in Executables part of Makefile). One of the graphic libraries is generated by me & is seen as (libPltDP.a). Even when I compile taxi_D with static flag and use it, I get an error.And I only get issues with 'taxi_D' which uses graphic libraries , others work fine.

This is the terminal output from Mac , where I failed to compile it -

```
gfortran -fdefault-real-8 -g -fbacktrace -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-0  taxi_driver_dakota.o taxi.o init.o setup.o setbc.o setbl.o update.o globit.o parm.o disp.o nxyset.o rpqset.o axell.o resj.o res0.o plcalc.o ff3d.o setq.o rowops.o io.o mrchbl.o blsys.o bldif.o blvar.o blfun.o bltrn.o uicalc.o forces.o bsolve.o uplot.o plutil.o spline.o lefind.o filter.o gaussn.o userio.o upause.o modes.o readst.o lossmodel.o suction.o bladegenauto.o loft.o spln2d.o postproc.o txset.o grdgen.o  readai.o   setexp.o sgutil.o grdpar.o tcdes.o ttdes.o datparse.o diskout.o blade_volume.o dogleg.o dpmpar.o enorm.o fdjac1.o hybrd.o qform.o qrfac.o r1mpyq.o r1updt.o flowpath.o strmline.o bladedata.o lspfit.o cubicbspline.o -static ../libs/libPltDP.a -L/opt/X11/lib -o taxi_D -lX11
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [taxi_D] Error 1
```

For Mac (10.13.3) /Linux(Open-Sure) i just get an error of "ld" returning an error -1 , which should mean something goes wrong before linking.
For Win7(64) I get error of missing dll(libgcc-s-dw2-1.dll & libfortran-3.dll).

( GCC version - Mac  (Posix 6.3) , Linux - (Posix 4.5 ) , Win - 5.4 via MinGW/MSYS) 
I dont understand the intricate details of X11 and feel like some issues with linking and dont wanna do guess work. Even I checked with command 'ldd' & it always shows dependency of taxi_D with .so files.

Any suggestions would be very helpful here. Thanks in advance !

```
PLTLIB = ../libs/libPltDP.a 
PLTLIB1 = ../libs/libPltDP.a -L/usr/X11/lib
SPLIT = ../tcttdes
UNAME := $(shell uname)

OBJSOL = .... (contains object files) (omitted)

fast: FCOMP = gfortran
fast: FLG    = -fdefault-real-8 -g -fbacktrace -ffixed-form -Wline-truncation -fdollar-ok -ffixed-line-length-none
fast: F90OPTS = -fdefault-real-8 -g -fbacktrace -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-0 
fast: FLGOPT =  $(FLG)
fast: FLGN   =  $(FLG)
fast: tcdes ttdes taxi_driver taxi_D

# Source files - Compilation ......(omiited)
#*****************************************************************************
#Executables # 
#*****************************************************************************

ifeq ($(UNAME),Linux)   
    taxi_D: taxi_driver_dakota.o $(OBJSOL)
    $(FCOMP) $(F90OPTS) taxi_driver_dakota.o $(OBJSOL) $(PLTLIB1) -o taxi_D -lX11
else
    taxi_D: taxi_driver_dakota.o $(OBJSOL)
    $(FCOMP) $(F90OPTS) taxi_driver_dakota.o $(OBJSOL) $(PLTLIB) -o taxi_D -lgdi32
endif
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To get help with this you need to include
in your post, at least, the exact command you are using to run Make and the
unedited output of the failing build. "I just get an error of "ld" returning an error -1",
for example, is not actually true. That's what is output *after* the linkage
has failed, but you haven't recognised the significant error message.

Comment: Thank your @MikeKinghan , I have edited my Q to include the terminal output ! Please see if it make sense or should I include some more info